# Implements Jmeter java request : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: classnotfoundexception, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I use dependency of jmeter 5.0 in my custom project pom .

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After compiling I copy jar to lib/ext in jmeter5.0 source project pulling from github , and debug by runing `NewDriver`, then i found the function `org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.ExtendsClassFilter#isChildOf` at `Class.forName(strClassName, false, contextClassLoader)` throw exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxxx.xxxx`, `strClassName` has printed my own classs, so it means my class has been scaned?

```java
private final ClassLoader contextClassLoader
    = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); // Potentially expensive; do it once

private boolean isChildOf(
        Class<?>[] parentClasses, String strClassName, ClassLoader contextClassLoader) {
    try {

        // Here is exception line
        Class<?> targetClass = Class.forName(strClassName, false, contextClassLoader);

        if (!targetClass.isInterface()
                && !Modifier.isAbstract(targetClass.getModifiers())) {
            return Arrays.stream(parentClasses)
                    .anyMatch(parent -> parent.isAssignableFrom(targetClass));
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedClassVersionError | ClassNotFoundException
            | NoClassDefFoundError | VerifyError e) {
        log.debug(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

My code

```java
public class JmeterSupportTest extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {
  xxxx;
}
```

Anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

It is ok now. Couse of plugin compile which did not add depend jars , and config pom add `maven-assembly-plugin` will solve

Answer (score 0):

1. If there are any extra libraries which are being used in your Java Request sampler implementation - they should go to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (see [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) user manual entry for more details) or you can think of using i.e. [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) to create "uber" or "fat" .jar containing all the dependencies
2. According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity
3. In addition to point 2 what you're pulling from Github is master (unless you switch to the [`v5_0 tag`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/v5_0) so make sure that the source is matching JMeter dependencies, just in case sources for each respective version can be found at [JMeter Archives page](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/source/)